# python remove info from readlines() that doesn't match a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading a file, then save that information with readlines(). I then check to see if any of the data from one of my lists is in readlines. The problem I am facing is removing all the information from readlines that isn't in my list, so readlines only contains the information that is in my list, that is if there are any matches. When I say match, I mean if any of the words are found in any order.  Could someone please help point me in the right direction? Thank you. I am using python 2.7 and am reading utf-8 files.

Edit: I am reading files and stores their information to readlines(), I then use my list to check and see if the file contains what I am looking for. If it does, then I want to remove all the data from readlines(), except the match found from my list. I save the matches to a text file. I hope this makes sense. If I am going about this the right way, please let me know.

Edit2: I am reading a file and then using readlines, which stores the data from that file in my readlines() variable. I know it would be helpful to share my code, but I am not allowed to do so.

Edit 3: Pseudo code

```
alist= ['hamburger','cow','meat'] 
openit = open.codecs('afile.html','utf-8-sig') 
justreadit = openit.readlines()
for alist in justreadit:
    print "found matches"
```

comment: remove any data that is not a list. When I tried putting in the pound sign as a normal comment, it didn't work.
edit4: I am looking for any of the words in the file in alist. No order, I just need to find the word and save it to a text file.

Comment: Why do you want to remove information from readlines? Can't you just store all the information that is in your list from readlines in a new variable?

Comment: If I've misunderstood, please post some code for clarification.

Comment: @FrankCangialosi, I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "saving their information to readlines()"? `readlines` is a method on a file object usually, so there's no way that I know of to save something to it. One good way to clarify this sort of thing if you're not sure how to express it is to actually include some of your current code in the question (try to make it a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @Blckknght, I've edited my question. I am unable to share code.

Comment: `readlines()` (with the parentheses) is not a valid variable name. As this question stands, I don't think you're going to get any answers, since it's not at all clear what you're doing or what you need to add.

Comment: @Blckknght, I added in some psuedo code to help explain the issue.

Comment: @FrankCangialosi I put some psuedo code up.

Comment: `file.readlines()` returns a list of lines (one line in the file -- one item in the list). You want to save lines that match some list of words. You should clarify what "match" means in *your case*. Do you want to save lines that contain *any* word from the `alist` list of words or do you want to save lines that contain *all* words from `alist` or do you want to save lines that contain nothing but words from `alist` and in the same order (what about punctuation, additional whitespace, etc)? Also you should clarify where do you want to put the result: leave it as a list or overwrite input file?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I am trying to find any of the words in no particular order and then save it to a text file. I edited my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me see if I'm understanding this right.

You have a file that looks something like this:

```
I am a farmer
Sometimes, I farm chickens
I also have a cow
I like to eat hamburger meat
But not lamb
```

You want to grab the third and fourth lines out of this, because the third line has `"cow"`, and the fourth line has both `"hamburger"` and `"meat"`. If this is a correct understanding of your problem, here is code that will achieve that (assuming the above text is saved to `afile.html` in the current working directory).

```
word_list = ['hamburger', 'cow', 'meat']
with open('afile.html', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    for word in word_list:
        if word in line:
            print(line)
            break
```

Result:

```
I also have a cow

I like to eat hamburger meat
​
```

Is this the result you wanted?

Note that there are many ways this could fail. For example, the line `I LIKE COW` would not be printed, because `"COW"` is not in the same case as `"cow"`. The line `"I like cows"` would be printed, because the substring `"cow"` is found in that line (even though the *word* "cow" isn't). Because the specification in your question is unclear about these things, I have not tried to guess at which of these behaviors you do or do not want.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried so many different ways to try to complete this, but they all failed. Thank you!! I'll have to solve why it is putting out the same information 3 times when there is only one match, but this was so helpful. @senshin

Comment: @user3148596: it may print matching line multiple times e.g., `"I like to eat hamburger meat"` is printed twice because it contains two words (`'hamburger'` and `'meat'`) from the `word_list`. Also it prints unnecessary newlines because `.readlines()` doesn't strip it from a line and `print` adds its own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this, but I think that since file.readlines() returns a list, with each list entry being a line from the target file.  To only return matches, I would:

```
justreadit=openit.readlines()
matchlist=[]
    for i in justreadit:
        for h in alist:
            if h==i:
              outputlist.append(i)
    return outputlist
```

Comment: Where does the value outputlist and matchlist come from? is outputlist a file object variable?

Comment: I tried that code and it resulted in an error. I fixed the error, but it didn't do anything.   I've tried several solutions similar to that before posting and all of them fail.